# Как объявить абстрактный итератор?

Tags: c++, полиморфизм, итераторы

Пишу итератор для хэш-таблицы. Таблица может быть двух видов, поэтому использую полиморфизм. Нужно объявить итератор, но возникает ошибка:

> C2555 CCHash<T,K>::begin: возвращаемый тип перегруженной виртуальной
> функции отличается от "AbstractHash<T,K>::begin" и не является
> ковариантным

И точно такая же для `AbstractHash<T,K>::end`.

`AbstractHash`:

```
class AbstractHash
{
public:

    class iterator {
    public:

        virtual const iterator& operator=(const iterator&) = 0;
        virtual T& operator*() = 0;
        virtual const iterator& operator++() = 0;
        virtual const iterator operator++(int) = 0;
        virtual const iterator& operator--() = 0;
        virtual const iterator operator--(int) = 0;

        virtual const bool operator==(const iterator&) = 0;
        virtual const bool operator!=(const iterator&) = 0;

    };

    virtual const iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual const iterator end() = 0;

};
```

Наследник `CCHash`:

```
class CCHash : public AbstractHash <T, K>
{

    class iterator {
    public:

        const iterator& operator=(const iterator&);
        T& operator*();
        const iterator& operator++();
        const iterator operator++(int);
        const iterator& operator--();
        const iterator operator--(int);

        const bool operator==(const iterator&);
        const bool operator!=(const iterator&);

    };

    const iterator begin(); //здесь ошибка
    const iterator end(); //здесь ошибка

};
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее про два вида хеш-таблицы? Проще всего было бы отказаться от полиморфизма, возможно заменить его CRTP.

Comment: Два вида хэш-таблиц, которые отличаются методами разрешения коллизий: с помощью цепочек коллизий и с помощью открытой адресации. Про CRTP не слышал раньше.

Comment: Покажите полный код с объявлением шаблонов. Если навесить шаблоны на оба класса [вот так](https://pastebin.com/5Xg5JMLQ) то все компилируется

Answer (score 1):

У вас определено два разных вложенных класса `iterator`. Один `AbstractHash::iterator`, а второй `CCHash::iterator` соответственно. Это два разных класса, между которыми нет никакого отношение наследования, в отличие от оригинальных классов AbstractHash и CCHash. Соответственно когда в CCHash возвращаете для виртуальной функции begin тип `CCHash::iterator` выдается ошибка, так как в базовом классе AbstractHash begin возвращает тип `AbstractHash::iterator`, в который `CCHash::iterator` не может быть сконвертирован.

Comment: Добавил class iterator : AbstractHash <T, K>::iterator, но ошибка осталась та же